# How do I trace a response to its original answer if the answers are randomized?

Tags: python

First of all, I apologize in advance as I'm new to Python so my lines of codes might be messy!

So here's what I'm trying to achieve, I'm trying to create like a quiz where the questions are randomized each trial and the answers are randomized each time as well. The codes below are partial of my coding and I'm kinda stuck at how do I approach the "randomized answers" part. The users can choose their answers by typing "1", "2" or "3" but since the answers are always randomized, how do I match the answers that the user have chosen back to its original answer?

```
marks = 0
questions = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3']
combination = ['Q1', 'Option 1 Q1'], ['Q2', 'Option 2 Q2'], ['Q3', 'Option 1 Q3']
answers = [['Option 1 Q1'], ['Option 2 Q1'], ['Option 3 Q1']], [['Option 1 Q2'], ['Option 2 Q2'], ['Option 3 Q2']], [['Option 1 Q3'], ['Option 2 Q3'], ['Option 3 Q3']]
selected_answers = []
random.shuffle(questions)

def shuffling():
    random.shuffle(answers[0])
    random.shuffle(answers[1])
    random.shuffle(answers[2])

question = 0
while question < 8:
    if questions[0] == 'Q1':
        shuffling()
        print(combination[0][1])
        print(answers[0][0], answers[0][1], answers[0][2])
        chosen = input('Enter 1 for the first answer, 2 for the second answer and 3 for the third one: ')
        selected_answers.append(chosen)
        del questions[0]
```

Comment: You should read more about dictionary type and then use key value pair structure for the question and answers. So that you can always get the correct answer or question with it's key. And for displaying you can display them in random order.

Comment: Dictionary type should work well in this scenario

Answer (score 1):

There are various obvious solutions:

You should at least record the comparison with the original position after each time you generate the results, which will help you judge.

Or you can consider playing the table, using some determined random seeds.

You really should know about dictionaries. Storing data as key-value pairs has advantages and is more efficient in this regard.